# How to add a user into a specific domain using CMD?

Tags: cmd, dns

In Windows 7, let's say I want to create a user in a specific domain using CMD. If the username is user.name, the password is password and the domain is DMN (the domain my computer is currently connected to), what would the command be? I know the syntax for the `net user` command is

```
net user [<UserName> {<Password> | *} [<Options>]] [/domain]
```

but i've attempted the command

```
net user user.name password /ADD DMN
```

and it doesn't work.

What should I do? Is there a proper command for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't name the domain, the command executes on the current domain: `NET USER user.name password /ADD /DOMAIN`.

Comment: @Compo Why don't you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new domain user with `NET USER` you don't name the domain. The command executes on the current domain as below.

```bat
NET USER user.name password /ADD /DOMAIN
```